# jQuery check an hidden checkbox onclick

Tags: jquery

I am on jQuery 1.3.2

I need a very simple code.

I have 4 checkboxes.

One of these checkboxes is hidden.

I want that when one of the 3 visible checkboxes is clicked the hidden one will be automatically checked.

So I have

```
<input type="checkbox" style="display:none" id="hiddenOne">
<input type="checkbox" style="display:block" id="visible2">
<input type="checkbox" style="display:block" id="visible3">
<input type="checkbox" style="display:block" id="visible4">
```

So if I click on any visible2 3 or 4 the hiddenOne will be automatically checked.

Is there a way to do that in jQuery?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to clear the hidden checkbox if all the visible ones are clear?

Comment: Yes that would be great too. So check the hidden one when one of those visible is checked. Uncheck the hidden one when no of those visible is checked. That would be fanstastic. If you can help me I will give you a point and an accepted answer =D. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will check if any of the three visible's are checked, if any are then show the hidden one and check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/S6SFZ/

**HTML:**

```
<label id="hiddenLabel" style="display:none"><input type="checkbox" id="hiddenOne"> Hidden One</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="visible2" class="visiChk"> Visible 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="visible3" class="visiChk"> Visible 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="visible4" class="visiChk"> Visible 4</label>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// update if any of the three are checked/unchecked
$('.visiChk').change(function() {
    var hiddenOne = $('#hiddenLabel')[0];

    // Are any of them checked ?
    if ($('.visiChk:checked').length > 0) {
        hiddenOne.style.display = 'block';
        hiddenOne.checked = true;
    } else {
        hiddenOne.style.display = 'none';
        hiddenOne.checked = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. The hidden checkbox is not checked. This is also visible in your demo. It just shows, but it is not checked at all